# Placeholder App: Advanced filters for lonely posts

Tags: app, placeholder

### About

This app is not yet written. It will help me write some more advanced queries and analytics, for the purpose of the Code Review site but probably applicable to any SE site.

#### License

https://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/

#### Platform

Cross-platform Python CLI

### Contact

https://stackexchange.com/users/121000/reinderien

### Code

Python, so far.

### Metadata

Client ID: 17769

OAuth domain: stackexchange.com